I get error 40532 when I try to connect to Azure SQL
I am trying to connect to my azure sql database with the script below.
But I get the message error code = 40532
I have added my IP address to my firewall.
I can log in via portal.azure.com and open the Play SQL database.
What am I doing wrong?
<?php
    // Variables to tune the retry logic.
    $connectionTimeoutSeconds = 30;  // Default of 15 seconds is too short over the Internet, sometimes.
    $maxCountTriesConnectAndQuery = 3;  // You can adjust the various retry count values.
    $secondsBetweenRetries = 4;  // Simple retry strategy.
    $errNo = 0;
    $serverName = "sql-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx.database.windows.net";
    $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"AdventureWorks",
       "Uid"=>"someone@somewhere.nl", "PWD"=>"itssecret", "LoginTimeout" => $connectionTimeoutSeconds);
    $conn = null;
    $arrayOfTransientErrors = array('08001', '08002', '08003', '08004', '08007', '08S01');
    for ($cc = 1; $cc <= $maxCountTriesConnectAndQuery; $cc++) {
        // [A.2] Connect, which proceeds to issue a query command.
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
        if ($conn === true) {
            echo "Connection was established";
            echo "<br>";

            $tsql = "SELECT Name FROM Production.ProductCategory";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
            if ($stmt === false) {
                echo "Error in query execution";
                echo "<br>";
                die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo $row['Name'] . "<br/>" ;
            }
            sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
            sqlsrv_close( $conn);
            break;
        } else {
            // [A.4] Check whether the error code is on the list of allowed transients.
            $isTransientError = false;
            $errorCode = '';
            if (($errors = sqlsrv_errors()) != null) {
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    $errorCode = $error['code'];
                    $isTransientError = in_array($errorCode, $arrayOfTransientErrors);
                    if ($isTransientError) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!$isTransientError) {
                // it is a static persistent error...
                echo("Persistent error suffered with error code = $errorCode. Program will terminate.");
                echo "<br>";
                // [A.5] Either the connection attempt or the query command attempt suffered a persistent error condition.
                // Break the loop, let the hopeless program end.
                exit(0);
            }
            // [A.6] It is a transient error from an attempt to issue a query command.
            // So let this method reloop and try again. However, we recommend that the new query
            // attempt should start at the beginning and establish a new connection.
            if ($cc >= $maxCountTriesConnectAndQuery) {
                echo "Transient errors suffered in too many retries - $cc. Program will terminate.";
                echo "<br>";
                exit(0);
            }
            echo("Transient error encountered with error code = $errorCode. Program might retry by itself.");
            echo "<br>";
            echo "$cc attempts so far. Might retry.";
            echo "<br>";
            // A very simple retry strategy, a brief pause before looping.
            sleep(1*$secondsBetweenRetries);
        }
        // [A.3] All has gone well, so let the program end.
    }
?>

I m not sure what ive tried but nothings is working. I think it has to do with rights or something. But I can't figure it out.

looks like you are using a user account "Uid"=>"someone@somewhere.nl" ? Are you sure the password is right for this user account? Otherwise Have you tried with sql account or service principal?

Thank you for the tip.
The username and password are correct. I can log in to my Azure SQL database with this  username and password and create queries. In DBeaver username and password also work.

Here you can see a discussion of the error code you received. Quoting the investigation:

To investigate the issue, you need to check Azure SQL Server met 2 conditions.

Public network access enabled for select networks

The source virtual network assigned to the VM not listed





In our scenario the virtual machine configured with virtual network named “virtualmachine_group-vnet” and subnet “default”.


And the mitigation:

Add the virtual network rule for the originating subnet in the ‘Networking’ section to Azure SQL Server “Networking” section in public access.


After adding the virtual network to Azure SQL Server, you should now be able to log on to azuresqlserver1.

